# Store multiple print output values from for loop into a list or variable

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, variables

I am a few days into python and pandas and I am running into a situation that I can not seem to resolve on my own. I have a for loop to fetch status codes and print out the results if they meet certain criteria. The for loop I have is as followed:

For loop:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

response_full_result = []

for url in url_list:
    try:
       response = requests.get(url)
       response_full_result.append(response)

       # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
       response.raise_for_status()

    except HTTPError as http_err:
       failed_result.append(http_err)
       print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  
    except Exception as err:
       print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  
    else:
       print('Success!')
```

What this for loop does is, it iterates through a column on a .csv and executes a get call to fetch status codes. Now, what this also does is print out exceptions as specified in the order they are executed. For **example**, if first three rows of column are: 200,400,NaN -, result will be: success, HTTP error, and Other Error (respectively)

**Desired Result**: I understand by design it is printing as expected - what I would like is for **all** the outputs to be stored in a variable / List that I can work with later. i.e. `success, HTTP error, Other Error` - Is there a way to do this? I tried `append` method, and `pickle` means I will have to convert to dictionary which is not ideal. Is there a way to do this in Python or Pandas?

Also, thanks to [this doc for providing for loop](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#the-get-request) - it is not mine. I am using PyCharm on Python 3.9. I am new to this and just started last week, I have found a lot of things but was unable to find an answer that helped me in my particular situation. Maybe I missed this - apologies.

Thank you to anyone who can help and give suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new list, for example `status_codes` and append the status to it after each iteration. Then you can use `zip()` to tie URL and status codes together or create new dataframe. For example:

```py
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

response_full_result = []

url_list = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "https://xxx.domain.example",
]

status_codes = []  # <-- here we store status codes

for url in url_list:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response_full_result.append(response)

        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        failed_result.append(http_err)
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}")
        status_codes.append("HTTP error")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Other error occurred: {err}")
        status_codes.append("Other error")
    else:
        print("Success!")
        status_codes.append("success")

print()

# print the results - use `zip()`
for url, status in zip(url_list, status_codes):
    print("{:<30} {}".format(url, status))

print()

# create a dataframe and write it to csv:
df = pd.DataFrame({"URL": url_list, "Status": status_codes})
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
Success!
Success!
Other error occurred: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.domain.example', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1e1c5e4100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

https://www.google.com         success
https://www.yahoo.com          success
https://xxx.domain.example     Other error

                          URL       Status
0      https://www.google.com      success
1       https://www.yahoo.com      success
2  https://xxx.domain.example  Other error
```

And creates `data.csv`:

```
URL,Status
https://www.google.com,success
https://www.yahoo.com,success
https://xxx.domain.example,Other error
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! This worked and you anticipated where I was going to go on my next steps. I notice something I have not seen before, `{:30}` in code block for `zip` - is this a zip feature or does it mean something in python for object? I will look into zip more in depth - Thank you again for the assistance and guidance. Truly appreciate it.

Comment: @knowledgealways `{:<30}` is just string formatting, meaning to align the domain name to left (30 characters wide) - it's just for pretty print

Comment: Ah, I suspected and now you confirmed it, appreciate the pretty print in mind. And now after studying your edits, I see you appended each print `output` to same variable: `status_codes`, then use `zip` and after formatting created new* dataframe to work with... - , Thank you very much for help in accomplishing my task (: